# Sending Base64 Image Source code by html form with javascript

Tags: javascript, php, forms, base64url

why is the sending of a base64 code so slow?
I got a base64 coded image string
and if i submit the value by html form it needs 40 seconds for transfering the data
i need the image to save with php

I tried already with lzw Compression but it doesn't helped a lot
just this code adds value to the form.

```
var crop = $('#image').data('cropbox');
    var val = crop.getDataURL();
    var val2 = val.compress();

    document.getElementById('img_base').value = val2;
```

if i submit the form a have to wait that long, it's not acceptable

Comment: Data increase by 30% when using base64 encoded string. This won't compress well.

Comment: You'd be better off using `FormData` and `$_FILES`.

Comment: im interested in a solution with $_FILES, how to ?